# Dynamically adding event handler to select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically add an event listener to a select box.

With this code I just don't get any response, so no alert box:

```
var table = $('<table></table>');

var row = $('<tr><td></td></tr>').html('<select id="sel1"><option>test</option><option>test2</option></select>');

$("sel1").on('change', function() {
  alert(this.val());
});

table.append(row);

$('#mydiv').append(table);
```

Also, how can I add the select box between the `td`?

Currently, it's added between the `tr`, `td` simply isn't there.

**[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pq2no59r/)**

Comment: Check jQuery `on()` DOC, you should just delegate event to any static container and passing `selector` parameter or bind event once element is added to the DOM. That's said, there are many many things wrong in your posted code... See once fixed https://jsfiddle.net/pq2no59r/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pq2no59r/8/)**

You should use event delegation **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** when you deal with fresh DOM added dynamically :

```
$("#mydiv").on('change', '#sel1', function() {
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

**NOTES :**

1. You should add `id` selector before `sel1` it should be `#sel1`.
2. `.val()` is a jquery method you can't call it on javascript object like `this.val()` it should be `$(this).val()`.
3. The current code will not add select inside `td` it will add it directely inside `tr` tag so you could replace :

   ```
   var row = $('<tr><td></td></tr>').html('<select id="sel1"><option>test</option>
   <option>test2</option></select>');
   ```

   By :

   ```
   var row = $('<tr></tr>').html('<td><select id="sel1"><option>test</option><option>
   test2</option></select></td>');
   ```

Hope this helps.

---

### Working Snippet

```js
var table = $('<table></table>');

var row = $('<tr></tr>').html('<td><select id="sel1"><option>test</option><option>test2</option></select></td>');

$("#mydiv").on('change', '#sel1', function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});

table.append(row);

$('#mydiv').append(table);
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: It's still not a full answer ... see the small remark of the OP at the end of the question

Comment: What if the select boxes (and hence the event handlers) are also added dynamically? So I would have the event handler fired multiple times.

Comment: You could give your selects the same class then you have just to add one event and it will work for all the rest, like : `$("body").on('change', '.global_class', function() {`.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of points to note in your code

---

**1)** **Wrong Selector `$("sel1")`**

The problem in your code is `$("sel1")` you need to select by id using `#` so it should be `$("#sel1")`. So your code would be like

```
$("#sel1").on('change', function() {
 alert(this.val());
});
```

---

**2)** **Bind event after appending the HTML to DOM or Use Event Delegation**
  Your code should be places in this order **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pq2no59r/5/)**

```
var table = $('<table></table>');

var row = $('<tr><td></td></tr>').html('<select id="sel1"><option>test</option><option>test2</option></select>');    

table.append(row);

$('#mydiv').append(table);// now the element is added to DOM so bind event

$("#sel1").on('change', function() {
  alert($(this).val()); // note here I changes this.val() to $(this).val()
});
```

**Or** another option is using event delegation **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pq2no59r/6/)**

To add event's to dynamic elements use the **event delegation**

```
 $('body').on('change',"#sel1", function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

---

**3)** **To place the select tag inside td use the below syntax**

```
 var row = $('<tr></tr>').html('<td><select id="sel1"><option>test</option><option>test2</option></select></td>');
```

Wrap the `td` along with the `select` tag and not inside the `tr` **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pq2no59r/7/)**

Comment: Missing part of the question ... see my comment on other answers

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the change event after appending to the page:

```
var table = $('<table></table>');

var row = $('<tr><td></td></tr>').html('<select id="sel1"><option>test</option><option>test2</option></select>');  

table.append(row);

$('#mydiv').append(table);

$("#sel1").on('change', function() {
   alert(this.val());
});
```

And also you have forgotten the # id selector for "sel1"

Comment: Missing part of the question ... see the OP's remark right before the end of the question

Answer (score 0):

There are three major issues in your code

1.The id selector must start with `#`

```
$("#sel1").on('change', function() {
```

2.You should bind the change listener only *after* you appended the element, because it just doesn't exist in the DOM before

3.With

```
$('<tr><td></td></tr>')
```

you'll get a jquery reference to the row (the `<tr>` element). Then with `.html()` you are replacing the content of the row (including the `<td>` of course)